# Derivation of the formula for the area of a regular polygon given the side length.

Tags: geometry, area, polygons

There are many formulas for finding the area of a regular polygon- but this is the one I am interested in:

$$A=\frac{S^2n}{4\tan(\frac{\pi}{n})}$$

where $n$ is the number of sides, and $S$ is the length of each side. Like I said, I would like to know how it is derived.

Comment: This is explained quite nicely here: 
http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/regular-polygons.html

Comment: Damn, this was actually really easy in hindsight. If only I had known about radian measure at the time- I figured out division into triangles- that was not what limited me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** "Triangulate" your polygon, i.e. decompose it in $n$ triangles and measure the area of one of them (they are all same). Note that they are all isosceles (because the polygon is regular) and you can easily compute their angles. So you may take the altitude of it passing through the center of the polygon and then apply basic trigonometric formulas.

Comment: For an even quicker version of this, cut each of these sectors in half to get $2n$ right triangles and compute their area.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's $n$ times the area of a single "wedge" of the polygon. So I just need to show the wedge has area $S^2/(4 \tan (\pi/n))$.

For that, consider a circle of radius $R$, with a wedge going from $-\pi/n$ to $\pi/n$. The area of that wedge is twice the area of the half-wedge, from $0$ to $\pi/n$. That area in turn is half the base times the height, i.e., it's $\frac{1}{2} R \sin (\pi/n) R \cos(\pi/n)$. So one wedge has area 
\begin{align}
W &= R \sin (\pi/n) R\cos(\pi/n)\\
& = R^2 \sin^2 (\pi/n) \frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sin(\pi/n)}\\
\end{align}
Now $R \sin(\pi/n)$ is half the length of a side of the polygon, i.e. it's $S/2$, so this becomes
\begin{align}
W &= R \sin (\pi/n) R\cos(\pi/n)\\
& = R^2 \sin^2 (\pi/n) \frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sin(\pi/n)}\\
&= (S/2)^2 \frac{\cos(\pi/n)}{\sin(\pi/n)}\\
&= (S^2/4) \frac{1}{\tan(\pi/n)}.
\end{align}
Thus the total area is $n$ times this, i.e., 
$$
(S^2/4)n \frac{1}{\tan(\pi/n)}.
$$