# Area of regular octagon

Tags: geometry

Prove that the area of an octagon with side *a* can be computed by the formula:
$$S=2a^2(1+\sqrt 2)$$
I tried to prove this by the area of 8 isoscles triangles inside the octagon, but I didn't manage to find the area of those triangles.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868161/derivation-of-the-formula-for-the-area-of-a-regular-polygon-given-the-side-lengt

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1579345/determine-the-area-of-a-regular-octagon-with-vertices-on-the-unit-circle/1579381

Answer (score 0):

Divide the octagon into $8$ isosceles triangles each having their apex at the centre of the octagon. Each apical angle is $45^\circ$ and each base angle is $\frac{180^\circ-45^\circ}{2}$

The side length $s$ of each such triangle can be found with the sine rule.

$s = \frac{a}{\sin 45^\circ}\sin \frac{180^\circ-45^\circ}{2} = a\sqrt 2 \cos \frac{45^\circ}{2}$

The area of each triangle is then $\frac 12 s^2 \sin 45^\circ = \frac{a^2}{\sqrt 2}\cos^2 \frac{45^\circ}{2} = \frac{a^2}{\sqrt 2} \frac{1 + \cos 45^\circ}{2} = \frac 14 a^2 (1 + \sqrt 2)$ where the second last step used the half angle formula.

The area of the octagon is therefore eight times that, which is $2a^2(1 + \sqrt 2)$

Comment: How do we know a centre exists?

Answer (score 0):

Join all the vertices of the regular octagon to the centre. This would give us 8 isosceles triangles, each with base $a$ and the angle at the vertex would be $45$ degrees. Drop a perpendicular from the vertex and now:
$tan(\frac{45}{2}) = (\frac{a}{2})(height)$.
Area of the triangle = $(\frac{1}{2})(a)(height)$ = $(\frac{1}{2})(a)$
$\frac{tan(\frac{45}{2})}{\frac{a}{2}}$ 
Now multiply this by 8 and you will get the required expression.